# IIS7 can't connect to database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis-7

Our production server has suddenly started coming up with errors when connecting to the database. I get the error below on any database call from any web app on the server.

```
"A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error 
occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - 
The specified data could not be decrypted."
```

I don't even want, and never have connected to SQL Server with SSL so I don't know why it's doing this. The database works fine and I can access it using the dev versions of the apps from my office. The database is hoted remotely.

Comment: Our hosting provider did scheduled maintenance on the server last night and the sites were working when I left, but not this morning. Does anyone know what they could have changed?

Comment: maybe you keep the session on this database ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix, restarted the server all was well. If anyone has any info on why that would happend and how to prevent it that would be good though.

Answer (score 0):

SSL is used if encryption is enabled on the (SQL) server to encrypt the connection between the client and the server:

[image]

Sounds like a pooled connection(s) has gone stale/corrupted during whatever maintenance work they were carrying out.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you used in your case BCrypt.NET library, which is built with 2.0 framework version, within project that used later version (e.g. 4.0). I faced the same problem and it came that removing usage of BCrypt also removed the problem. The issue was solved with the following steps:

1. Download the latest BCrypt.Net source code from [BCrypt Codeplex](http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest);
2. Compile it with your project's version of framework (don't forget to put Configuration into Release mode - otherwise Hash method may cause overflow exceptions);
3. Use dll in your project.

Hope this helps anyone.